# CloudFront Signed URL always gives "No playable sources found" in JWPlayer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to set-up private signed url's for CloudFront streaming, but not luck. It works ok if CloudFront is set-up as public.

I'm using the AWS PHP SDK to create the signed url, using the code below.

I've used the API to check my key_pair_id is correctly set-up as an Active Trusted Signer.

And my S3 bucket is still public for now, https://cep-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/adam/video/2-1-1-1.mp4

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks!

```
    $cloudFront = \Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient::factory(array(
        'private_key' => $this->config['cep']['s3']['cf_secret'],
        'key_pair_id' => $this->config['cep']['s3']['cf_key_pair_id'],
    ));

    $expires = time() + 360000;
    $streamHostUrl = 'rtmp://si0ulh281c930.cloudfront.net';
    $resourceKey = 'adam/video/2-1-1-1.mp4';

    $signedUrlCannedPolicy = $cloudFront->getSignedUrl(array(
        'url'     => $streamHostUrl . '/' . $resourceKey,
        'expires' => $expires,
    ));

    return 'rtmp://si0ulh281c930.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/'.$signedUrlCannedPolicy;
```

Comment: Did you make any progress with this i am also having issues with signed urls thanks?

Comment: No, unfortunately we still haven't solved it.

Comment: I have also made the same. My player is not showing message. but it always loading infinitely.